# Converting cell array of string arrays to a double array

Tags: matlab

I have a 55X1 cell array. Each cell contains a 1X178 string array of numbers. I would like to convert all the cells to a double array, but in such a way that it forms a 55X178 double array.

Take, for example, the 55X1 cell array `dataCellOut = {each cell has a 1X178 string}`. I can use: `na=str2num(dataCellOut{1})` and this will output a 1X178 double array. I have tried using: `na=cellfun(@str2num, dataCellOut, 'UniformOutput', false)` and this does not work (error: "input must be a character vector or string scalar"). I have worked on this for awhile to no avail.

I hope this makes sense and if there is anything else that I can offer please don't hesitate to let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: According to the documentation, `str2num(dataCellOut{1})` should not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation to `str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

> The `str2num` function does not convert cell arrays or nonscalar string arrays, and is sensitive to spacing around `+` and `-` operators. In addition, `str2num` uses the `eval` function, which can cause unintended side effects when the input includes a function name. To avoid these issues, use `str2double`.

[`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html), however, does just as you want:

> `X = str2double(str)` converts the text in `str` to double precision values. [...] `str` can be a character vector, a cell array of character vectors, or a string array. [...] If `str` is [...] a string array, then `X` is a numeric array that is the same size as `str`.

Thus, this should work:

```
na = cellfun(@str2double, dataCellOut, 'UniformOutput', false);
na = cat(1,na{:});
```

Comment: Something to follow up with, though: say that the arrays were all one row, but had varying number of column elements. How would you go about concatenating then? I have considered the option of finding the largest number of columns and then padding all other rows with spaces (the arrays in this case are strings, not doubles); but I am not sure how exactly I would implement that.

Comment: @DymaxionFuller: That's a little bit more complicated, you can use `cellfun` to call a custom function that pads with zeros or with NaN (I would pad the double arrays, rather than the strings, so you can control what numbers to fill the empty locations with). Given a vector `x`, `x(178)=0` pads the vector with zeros. Padding with NaN is a little bit more involved, I think something like this would do the trick: `x=[x,nan(1,178-numel(x))]`.

Comment: So let me be a little bit more clear because I think I might have misled you a little. The double array is complete and that works great. There is, however, other data in the file I am importing that I would like to be able to place into an array--this data is string data. It is a 146X1 cell array and each cell contains a string vector and each vector has a variable number of columns. So my thought was to search through the 146 rows; find the largest col value, and then pad each of the other vectors out to that value; then use the `cat` function. I hope that is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This simple statement works for me.
str2num(char(cellstr_array))